# Passing data to PSCmdlet from its ArgumentTransformationAttribute

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

Generally, I'm trying to create a `PSCmdlet` that takes a parameter of a type that implements `IDisposeable` and requires disposal in order to avoid leaking resources.  I would also like to accept a `string` for that parameter and create an instance of that type, however if I create that object myself, then I need to dispose it before returning from `ProcessRecord`.

I'm using an `ArgumentTransformationAttribute` with my parameter in order to construct my `IDisposeable` object from a string, but I cannot find any way to pass data from that class to my `PSCmdlet` about whether I created the object or not.  For example:

```
[Cmdlet("Get", "MyDisposeableName")]
public class GetMyDisposeableNameCommand : PSCmdlet
{
    [Parameter(Mandatory = true, Position = 0), MyDisposeableTransformation]
    public MyDisposeable MyDisposeable
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        try
        {
            WriteObject(MyDisposeable.Name);
        }
        finally
        {
            /* Should only dispose MyDisposeable if we created it... */
            MyDisposeable.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

class MyDisposeableTransformationAttribute : ArgumentTransformationAttribute
{
    public override Object Transform(EngineIntrinsics engineIntrinsics, Object input)
    {
        if (input is PSObject && ((PSObject)input).BaseObject is MyDisposeable)
        {
            /* We were passed a MyDisposeable, we should not dispose it */
            return ((PSObject)input).BaseObject;
        }

        /* We created a MyDisposeable, we *should* dispose it */
        return new MyDisposeable(input.ToString());
    }
}
```

My best guess here is to subclass my `MyDisposeableClass` just to tag that it needs explicit disposal, but that seems fairly hacky, and while it works in this case, it obviously wouldn't work if I wanted to deal with a sealed class.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I simply use parameters that accept a type that wraps `MyDisposeable`.  My initial concern with doing this was that using an internal type for a parameter would impact the functions accessibility.  (Perhaps it would negatively impact documentation, but in a cmdlet the documentation is wholly controlled by an XML file.)

After some testing, there do not appear to be any problems using an internal class for a parameter and just letting the transformation accept public types.  So I simply create a wrapper class:

```
public class MyDisposeableWrapper
{
    public MyDisposeable MyDisposeable
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool NeedsDisposed
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public MyDisposeableWrapper(MyDisposeable myDisposeable, bool needsDisposed)
    {
        MyDisposeable = myDisposeable;
        NeedsDisposed = needsDisposed;
    }
}
```

And have the parameter take that instead.  In the transformation attribute, simply set `NeedsDisposed` based on whether the parameter took a `MyDisposeable` or constructed one.  eg:

```
if(input is MyDisposeable)
{
    return new MyDisposeableWrapper((MyDisposeable) input, false);
}
else
{
    /* construct MyDisposeable from the input */
    return new MyDisposeableWrapper(myDisposeable, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than subclassing, can you add a property to your MyDisposable class?

```
public class MyDisposable
{
    ...   
    public bool IsAttributeCreated { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your attribute code

```
/* We created a MyDisposeable, we *should* dispose it */
return new MyDisposeable(input.ToString()){IsAttributeCreated=true};
```

Finally in your finally block

```
finally
{
    /* Should only dispose MyDisposeable if we created it... */
    if (MyDisposable.IsAttributeCreated)
        MyDisposeable.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no, in this case `MyDisposeable` is from a library that I cannot modify, short of some reflection.